# Javascript function to include SSI depending on time and day of week

Tags: javascript, ssi

I'm looking for a piece of code which gets the time and day of the week and then includes SSI html depending on what comes back.

I've tried adapting Java and PHP, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP function include() and not use SSI.

For example

```
if (date("d") == 1) {
   include("firstday.html");
} else {
   include("default.html");
}
```

This code include file firstday.html for each first day of month and include default.html for others days.

For others cases you can read description of PHP function date()